# Receiving an 'else' without 'if' error

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Cortana2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //Declaring Variables (Add more commands) 
        String command;
        // Command will always stay the same
        // All strings below are commands to put in
        String Steam;
        String League;
        League=("League"); 
        Steam=("Steam");  
        command= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Give a valid command");

        if (command == null) {  
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is not a valid command. If you have forgotten what commands are valid, please refer to Devon for assistance");
            JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();
        } else if (command == League) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"D:/LeagueClient.exe\"");
        } else if (command == Steam) { 
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/Steam.exe\"");    
        }
    }
}
```

Not 100% sure why I'm getting the error. I've seen where others said to remove the semicolons from the 'if' statements but then nothing executes when I run the program and type in commands. Sorry if anything seems poorly formatted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (command == null);
```

Don't put a ";" at the end of your if/else statements.

> but then nothing executes when I run the program and type in commands

Don't use `==` to compare String.

Instead use the `String.equals(...)` method

Also variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm surprised how quickly people answered. My only issue now is that my null command isn't working properly. It should create a text box saying that the command is not valid, but instead it just closes the input box and ends the program. Any ideas?

Comment: @PLUR, `Basic debugging technique` (instead of asking a question in the forum every time you have a problem). Did you display the value of the command variable (using System.out.println())? If it is null it will display as null. Otherwise I would guess the value is an empty String ("").

Comment: Well I didn't mean null is a command by the way. Sorry about that. My wording isn't the best. But it's suppose to run as follows: If you type in League, it executes the League client, same with Steam. However, if you don't type in a valid command, or you leave it blank entirely, it will show the message. Null means nothing correct?

Comment: @PLUR, `Null means nothing correct?` - no that is not correct. The `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()`  returns a String. It could be a null String or it could be an empty string. Read the documentation from the API. It if isn't clear then you need to do some basic debugging. Don't assume the value will be null.

Comment: Why do you even care about null. You should just check for the two valid values first and then the else statement will display your error dialog if it is not one of the two valid values. That is what if somebody just type "a" and hits enter? That is also an invalid command.

Comment: I'm relatively new to Java, which is why I don't know all the terminology or how to efficiently format my work. My apologies. I did however just fix my program based off of what you said, and I now have everything working. I thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extraneous semicolon at the end of each test

```
else if (command == League); // <- remove these semicolons
```

You're also going to have grief using `==` to compare strings. Use `.equals()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Semicolon From If, Else If An Use equals Method After Your Code Looks Like This..

```
  command= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Give a valid command")

       {
                 if (command.equals(null)
                 {         
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is not a valid command. If you have forgotten what commands are valid, please refer to Devon for assistance");
                 JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();
                 }else if (command.equals(League))
                 {   
                 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"D:/LeagueClient.exe\"");
                 }else if (command.equals(Steam))
                 {  
                 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/Steam.exe\"");  
                 }   

        System.exit(0);
       }
```